# How to Import the Multipolygon with GeoJSON code in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, google-fusion-tables

**I have to import a MultiPolygon in Google Earth Engine**

and what I have is just this.

```
 {"type": "GeometryCollection", "geometries": [{"type": "MultiPolygon","coordinates": [[[[102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [102.0, 3.0], [102.0, 2.0]]], [[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]], [[100.2, 0.2], [100.8, 0.2], [100.8, 0.8], [100.2, 0.8], [100.2, 0.2]]]]}]}
```

I think this is of GeoJSON Format correct me if I am wrong.

Please explain how to import it as a MultiPolygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the coordinates as a `MultiPolygon` geometry.

```js
var multipoly = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(
  [[[[102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [102.0, 3.0], [102.0, 2.0]]], [[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]], [[100.2, 0.2], [100.8, 0.2], [100.8, 0.8], [100.2, 0.8], [100.2, 0.2]]]]
)

Map.addLayer(multipoly)
```

Comment: How would you import this if the GeoJSON had mixed geometry types (e.g. points, polygons, etc) and wanted to add it to the Map.drawingTools().addLayer as a geometry layer?